# Is $K_v \subset L_w$ if $w|v$ for number fields $K$ and $L$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $L/K$ is an extension of number fields and $w$ and $v$ are places of $L$ and $K$ respectively such that $w|v$ then is there an embedding $K_v\subset L_w$?

This is probably a trivial question to all algebraic number theorists but as a newcomer to the subject I don't know how to approach the problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute value $|\cdot|_w$ on $L_w$ restricted to $K$ equals $|\cdot|_v$, since $w|v$. Therefore the natural embedding $K\hookrightarrow L$ can be extended to $K_v$, since since any point in $K_v$ is represented by a Cauchy sequence wrt $|\cdot|_v$ and therefore is also a Cauchy sequence wrt $|\cdot|_w$ and thus is an element of $L_w$.